# Need help with IP filtering and port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, blocking, filtering

I have a static IP assigned to me by my ISP. I want to access a server running tomcat in our network from outside the LAN. Can any one give a few pointers, to what I need to do, and where to start from? I should be able to ssh, deploy builds from outside, and most importantly, show the product running on the server to clients.

Right now, typing the static IP in the browser from a PC on the LAN brings me to the Modem's login page(from where you change the various settings related to the modem, like setting the IP rules, or port forwarding, or related to wi-fi). I havent tried it from outside the network, but I am guessing it will be the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your modem / router device should have some kind of UI to configure "port forwarding". That's where you want to look. Telling us the make / model will help us help you. Generally, there should be somewhere to identify the protocol (TCP or UDP), the external port, the internal IP, and the internal port (though some dumb-as-rocks NAT routers won't allow you to "map" an external port to a different internal port).

You probably won't "see" the modem's UI when accessing the static IP from outside your network. The fact that you do from inside your network means that your modem / router might do  hairpin NAT, which can actually be very useful. ("Hairpin NAT" allows the router to accept traffic for its external IP address from the internal LAN and "turn around" that traffic back onto the internal LAN).

Having an off-site box that you can access w/ something like "LogMeIn", "GotoMyPC", etc, can be helpful for testing the configuration quickly.

Comment: the make is teracom, and the model is T2-B-Gawv1.4U10Y-BI. There is also a DMZ option in the UI. should I add the IP of the PC running the tomcat to it?